# Prevent Google Chrome from remembering window position on close

Tags: google-chrome, multiple-monitors, window

There's a computer that is only used for the youth service at my church. Sometimes, Google Chrome is used to display a web page during the service. The problem is, next time someone opens Chrome, it remembers that it was closed on the second monitor and pops up over there, which can interrupt the program. I need to force Chrome to always open on the primary monitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use next Chrome command line parameters (update a Chrome shortcut target):

- to specify the initial window position: `--window-position=x,y` and
- to specify the initial window size: `--window-size=w,h`, or
- to start the browser maximized, regardless of any previous settings: `--start-maximized`

So the target of a Chrome shortcut for starting Chrome window maximized could be as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --start-maximized
```